# I installed something via terminal, but wasn't in the home directory when it did it.

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I installed `npm` via terminal, but when I did it I wasn't in the *home folder*. Instead, I was in the folder for something I needed `npm` to install, where I was then prompted to use `sudo apt install npm`

When I open a new terminal window (which starts in the home folder) and type `npm`, it seems like it installed just fine, but I was wondering if there's any reason I may need to repeat the installation process since I wasn't in the home folder when I originally did it.

Comment: As a general rule: if it ain't broken, don't fix it. APT doesn't need to touch any home directory and you saw that the program works just fine. Don't worry. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apt` command does not care at all about your current working directory, just like most standard commands. You can invoke them from anywhere just fine.

If there is an exception to this, it will be documented in the manual page of that specific command. You can read it by typing `man COMMAND`, e.g. `man apt`. For example, the `find` command searches files below your current working directory by default if you don't specify a location.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to be in the home folder.
apt will put the system files where they need to be.
you can install from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

apt will put the files youve downloaded where they need to go!
Like if your downloading from the web they go into the downloads folder. So tell me if this works for you ten tell me! Thanks for the question!